# Should I use my personal laptop to login into company portal?

Tags: authentication, windows

My company has a portal https://company.com which can be accessed without vpn. In fact, it shows up in google search if you know the name of the portal. This portal grants access to email and non critical things like company social media etc. But, it does not give access to source control and such.

Is it advisable to access the company portal from my personal laptop ? One reason against this is that there is a chance that my personal laptop could have hidden malware because its used for non work stuff, nothing illegal though. Any other reasons for this ?

Comment: That's really a question about company policy. You seem to have a good understanding of the risks involved.

Comment: If your company has set up such a portal, then they obviously don't consider it a great risk.

Answer (score 1):

Access to company email is more than enough to cause anyone pause before accessing with a personal device. You might not have access to code repos, but you have access to a ***lot*** with email.

The problem here is having access to company emails on your personal device. Malware isn't a huge threat, but theft or compromise of your device is. If someone can gain access to your work email through your device (of dubious security), that's a problem.

That's just an initial response from someone who has written policy around such things given the few details you provide. I'd want your personal gear far away from corporate email.

Comment: Agree.  If the company policy allows publication of this portal site, then the company's IT/Security/Risk-Control folks have evaluated the risk:reward here and determined that allowing uncontrolled devices access is at least acceptable to the company, if not ultimately beneficial.  The OP has a grasp of the technical issues, but in the end this is often a company policy question, "Should we allow this type of access and is it OK with us?" which runs toward either "Yes, cool, lets setup a portal then." or "No, then lock it down."